# SQL Query: Data view with data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

I am trying to make an SQL query from a data extension with a data view, but i can't get it to work.

```
SELECT 
a.id as Id
, a.email as email
, a.FirstName as FirstName

from contact_salesforce a

left join _Open o
on o.SubscriberKey = a.id
```

it gives an error when i do the automation:

"Query failed during execution. Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object"

Data Extension fields:

Id Text 18

Email EmailAddress 254

FirstName Text  40

Comment: What is the update type of your query?  Do you have a primary key assigned in your target data extension?

Comment: It is a Query automation. Primary key is Id.

Comment: David means, is it an Add, Update, or Overwrite query.    You may want to add some context of what you're trying to accomplish with this query.  Since you have a primary key, you'll only have 1 record for each subscriber tied to 1 record from the _Open data view.  I think you're probably looking for a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: I'm sorry it's an update query.

Comment: @wfrankhuizen I provided an answer below.  But need to ask, what goal of your query.  The use of the "left join" will output subscribers that are both found and not found in the _open data view.

Comment: I used open in this example but i will use complaint. I want a list of all subscribers who filed complaints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query specified will return multiple rows if more than one open event is found for the particular subscriber.  You can add the keyword *distinct* to your query to insure only unique row of data are returned by your query.  This will eliminate the key violation.

```
SELECT distinct
a.id as Id
, a.email as email
, a.FirstName as FirstName

from contact_salesforce a

left join _Open o
on o.SubscriberKey = a.id
```

Normally, I avoid using the *distinct* keyword and opt for aggregating the query results in some way.  But since this query is only selecting columns from the **contact_salesforce** data extension, using *distinct* will work in this case.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT distinct
a.id as Id
, a.email as email
, a.FirstName as FirstName

from contact_salesforce a

left join _Open o
on o.SubscriberKey = a.id
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. This answer is what we call a _code dump_. It's a block of code with no explanation. Code dumps tend to be poor answers because they don't explain _what_ the issue is, _how_ to fix it, or _why_ the fix works. A good explanation will help people understand the problem so that they can (hopefully) avoid, or at least identify, similar problems in the future. Code dumps also tend to generate a lot of back-and-forth in the comments like "that didn't work" and "try this instead", which makes it hard for others to follow.